# Node.js child process catches python output correctly unless output comes after particular method

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express

I am trying to run a python script, and gather the printed output sent to the console using the following code in Node/Express:

```
app.post("/compute", (req, res) => {
   var data = req.body.mat;
   const value = runScript(data);
   value.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(data.toString());
   });
});

function runScript(data) {
   return spawn("python", [
      "-u",
      path.join(__dirname, "scripts/guess.py"),
      "--data",
      data,
   ]);
}
```

It runs the following python script (simplified):

```
def main(argv):
   opt, data = argv
   model.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.pt")
   print("Output")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The python script does exactly what it is meant to do when it is run in the terminal using `python guess.py --data 0010100101000`. The Node/Express does exactly what it is supposed to do, except when the print statement in the python code is after the line `model.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.pt"))`. When the print statement is before this line, the Node code catches the python output properly.

Does this have something to do with the method taking too long, and the Node code not catching new stdouts anymore? Or does it have to do with the python code accessing another file, messing with the stdout? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this line was throwing an error because the current working directory is different when I run the script from the terminal vs the node code. I just edited the path I passed to the method.